# How is $\int \frac{\frac{d y(x)}{dx}}{y(x)^2}dx = -\frac{1}{y(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

I just saw wolfram-alpha making following statement...

$\int \frac{\frac{d y(x)}{dx}}{y(x)^2}dx = -\frac{1}{y(x)}$

But I am very unsure how to get there.

I always thought I can cancel out the $dx$ and call it a day. Like so:

$\int \frac{\frac{d y(x)}{dx}}{y(x)^2}dx =  \int \frac{d y(x)}{y(x)^2}=\int \frac{d 1}{y(x)}=\frac{1}{y(x)}$

I suppose that's wrong, so where does the minus come from?

Comment: $dy(x)$ is not $d$ times $y(x)$, so the step when you end up with "$d1$" is wrong. Can you evaluate $\int \dfrac{dy}{y^2}$?

Comment: As @MarkS. said - ${dy(x)\neq d\times y(x)}$. $d$ is not a variable. It's very, very important to be careful with treating anything involving ${d}$ (meaning the differential operator) as a standard number. In your case - I believe ${\int \frac{\frac{dy(x)}{dx}}{y(x)^2}}$ is meant to be alternative notation to ${\int \frac{\frac{dy}{dx}}{y^2(x)}dx}$.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Yep. I get it now.

Comment: @Quotenbanane noice! Good to hear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to think of it as cancelling out the $dx$ but what is actually happening is this:
$$I=\int\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{1}{y^2}dx$$
$u=y(x)\Rightarrow du=y'dx\therefore dx=\frac{du}{y'}$
$$I=\int\frac{y'}{y'}\frac{1}{u^2}du=\int\frac{1}{u^2}du=-\frac{1}{u}+C=-\frac 1y+C$$

Comment: Ooooh thank you. That was simple and intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

You make a mistake when you think that $dy(x)$ is a product of $ d $ by $ y(x)$ and simplify.

You want to find
$$J=\int \frac{y'(x)}{y^2(x)}dx$$

So, you will make the substitution
$$t=y(x)$$

with
$$dt=y'(x)dx$$

It becomes
$$J=\int \frac{dt}{t^2}=-\frac 1t+C$$
$$=-\frac{1}{y(x)}+C$$

The minus comes from the fact that the derivative of $ g(x)=\frac{1}{x}=x^{-1} $ is
$$g'(x)=-x^{-2}=-\frac{1}{x^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

No. You shouldn't just cancel out the $\text{d}x$, since they aren't numbers, although they can be defined so it's possible to do such cancellation. But for now you should just subsitute.

On the other hand. you MUST NOT cancel out $\text{d}y(x)$ with $y(x)$. That's completely wrong, since $\text{d}$ is an operator, not something you multiply. .They are two different things.

That said, what you should do to make clearer those kind of integrals (and avoid getting confused) is to subsitute as I said earlier. Take $u(x)=y(x)$. Then $u'=\dfrac{\text{d}u(x)}{\text{d}x}=\dfrac{\text{d}y(x)}{\text{d}x}$. So

$\int \frac{\frac{d y(x)}{dx}}{y(x)^2}dx = \int \frac{u'}{u^2}\text{d}x=-\dfrac{1}{u}+C=-\frac{1}{y(x)}+C$, where the last step is ,ade undoing the substitution, and $C$ is a real constant. If you set $C=0$ you have a particular antiderivative for $\dfrac{\frac{y(x)}{\text{d}x}}{y(x)^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Cancel differential $dx$ in numerator and denominator in the finite differential sense,before returning to infinitesimals.

$$\int \dfrac{d \; y(x)}{y(x)^2} $$

If $y(x)=v, y'(x)=v'$ then directly integrating

$$\dfrac{-1}{v}+c$$

$$= -\dfrac{1}{y(x)}+c$$

Remember $ \int x^n dx= x^{n+1}/(n+1)+c$

Comment: This does work - but I think it isn't really a good idea (for Mathematical rigors sake) to say something like "cancel out the ${dx}$" since in general treating them as numbers will give incorrect results

Comment: With a single independent variable associated differentials understanding it could be allowed, like in $ dy= (dy/dx) dx =y' \; dx.$ It helps a lot in differential geometry and differential  equations. If context is proper I think conceptually in this case also  it is  in order.